# Spring Cloud Sidecar configuration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I have a very simple sidecar application - just the required annotations and the main method, like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar
public class SidecarApplication {
    ...
}
```

I also have a service sitting behind it, on the same host, which has a GET /joke endpoint.

The sidecar configuration:

```
server.port=5678
spring.application.name=joker

sidecar.port=8083
sidecar.home-page-uri=http://localhost:8083/
sidecar.health-uri=http://localhost:8083/health.json

management.security.enabled=false
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

However, when calling GET http://localhost:5678/joke, I get 404. If I call GET http://localhost:8083/joke, I do get a valid response.

Now, If I add this to the sidecar configuration:

```
zuul.routes.joker.url=http://localhost:8083/
```

then calling GET http://localhost:5678/joker/joke works as expected.

Am I missing something, or is this expected behavior? I would have expected no additional configuration to be necessary for the sidecar to route all incoming requests to the wrapped service, and I'd want the url to be used for accessing the service behind the sidecar not to need to contain a service name.

Comment: zuul being a gateway api, this seem tobe the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more notations like these in application.properties:

```
spring.application.name = joke
server.port = 5678

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http: // localhost: 9000 / eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = true
eureka.client.fetch-registry = true

sidecar.port = 8083
sidecar.health-uri = http: // localhost: 8083 / health

management.security.enabled = false

/ * example * /
zuul.routes.wstore.path = / wstore / **
zuul.routes.wstore.url = http: // localhost: 8083
```

In the application should have these 3 notations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SidecarApplication {...}
```

note this configuration was useful for spring-boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: What we ended up using is what I described in the question, and what georges confirmed in the comment to the original question. @EnableDiscoveryClient doesn't help, unless there's an explicit mapping from URL patterns to service ids in the sidecar configuration. Sorry to say this, but anything else, regarding configuration and in relation to the original question, is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Eureka` yes, the routing is transparent. The `sidecar` app registers itself with `Eureka` BUT sets `homePageUrl` value of Eureka `InstanceInfo` object to the actual host and port of your microservice. And this is the value your clients will use to make calls to your microservice.